# Modify CFG in LLVM

Tags: c++, optimization, llvm

Could I modify the CFG in LLVM and these modifications be written in IR file? I made an LLVM pass to modify basic block and edges sequence and I ran the pass by lli -load to emit the IR, but nothing happened I think I should use some commands to manipulate the original CFG with the required one. I read in the llvmdev that the CFG is manipulated by changing the basic block terminator.However, my main point to change the edges too.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the transformation passes in `lib/Transforms`. Most of them modify the IR. To run a pass that modifies IR and spit the modified IR back, use the `opt` tool.